# Is there a way to overlay a jumbotron over a carousel?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to overlay the [jumbotron](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/jumbotron/) component over the [carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/) to get a sort of website heading. What should I implement to get this working?

Comment: Have you tried anything that you can share the code here?

Comment: I treid to implement it viia positioning (postion: absolute;) and with the z-index, but I don't have any knowledge on how to get things started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not being very descriptive or giving us any code, however if I could assume your asking how to overlay two elements, you use the z-index property in CSS

Comment: I already sted above, that I tried to use the z-index property, but I don't know how to position them adobe each other.

Comment: absolute positioning may be another option depending on your website